# Remove Child From Firebase removes whole node swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following data structure:

```
"feed" : {
 "756135 Washington" : {
  "VbMvwmlNqGNUY44JmfPp" : {
    "downvotes" : "downvotes",
    "timestamp" : 1483396793247,
    "upvotes" : {
      "i5KHwJzhTTfA6FJ8Fb2qLHuLjHi2" : {
        "timestamp" : 1483396826253
      }
    },
  }
 }
}
```

Now I want to remove the `i5KHwJzhTTfA6FJ8Fb2qLHuLjHi2` node under `upvotes` but I still want the `upvotes` node to stay, just without any children. I'm using the following code, however this removes the whole node.

```
 ref?.child("feed").child(city_localizer_string!).child(id!).child("upvotes").child(uid).removeValue()
```

Answer (score 1):

Anything empty in firebase will always be removed automatically. Even if you try and create a new child with the value of nil it won't be added to your database.

Comment: so how do you suggest I get around this issue?

Comment: You will have to ensure your code can deal with the absence of the `upvotes` node.